# How to implement NOT IN for two DataFrames with different structure in Apache Spark

Tags: java, sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using Apache Spark in my Java application. 
I have two `DataFrame`s: `df1` and `df2`. The `df1` contains `Row`s with `email`, `firstName` and `lastName`. `df2` contains `Row`s with `email`.

I want to create a `DataFrame`: `df3` that contains all the rows in `df1`, which email is not present in `df2`.

Is there a way to do this with Apache Spark? I tried to create `JavaRDD<String>` from `df1` and `df2` by casting them `toJavaRDD()` and filtering `df1` to containing all emails and after that using `subtract`, but I don't know how to map the new `JavaRDD` to `ds1` and get a `DataFrame`.

Basically I need all Rows that are in `df1` whose email is not in `df2`.

```
DataFrame customers = sqlContext.cassandraSql("SELECT email, first_name, last_name FROM customer ");

DataFrame customersWhoOrderedTheProduct = sqlContext.cassandraSql("SELECT email FROM customer_bought_product " +
                            "WHERE product_id = '" + productId + "'");

JavaRDD<String> customersBoughtEmail = customersWhoOrderedTheProduct.toJavaRDD().map(row -> row.getString(0));

List<String> notBoughtEmails = customers.javaRDD()
                        .map(row -> row.getString(0))
                        .subtract(customersBoughtEmail).collect();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Spark 2.0.0+**

You can use `NOT IN` directly.

**Spark < 2.0.0**

It can be expressed using outer join and filter.

```scala
val customers = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  ("john@example.com", "John", "Doe"),
  ("jane@example.com", "Jane", "Doe")
)).toDF("email", "first_name", "last_name")

val customersWhoOrderedTheProduct = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  Tuple1("jane@example.com")
)).toDF("email")

val customersWhoHaventOrderedTheProduct = customers.join(
    customersWhoOrderedTheProduct.select($"email".alias("email_")),
    $"email" === $"email_", "leftouter")
 .where($"email_".isNull).drop("email_")

customersWhoHaventOrderedTheProduct.show

// +----------------+----------+---------+
// |           email|first_name|last_name|
// +----------------+----------+---------+
// |john@example.com|      John|      Doe|
// +----------------+----------+---------+
```

Raw SQL equivalent:

```scala
customers.registerTempTable("customers")
customersWhoOrderedTheProduct.registerTempTable(
  "customersWhoOrderedTheProduct")

val query = """SELECT c.* FROM customers c LEFT OUTER JOIN  
                 customersWhoOrderedTheProduct o
               ON c.email = o.email
               WHERE o.email IS NULL"""

sqlContext.sql(query).show

// +----------------+----------+---------+
// |           email|first_name|last_name|
// +----------------+----------+---------+
// |john@example.com|      John|      Doe|
// +----------------+----------+---------+
```

Comment: Thank you. The first example worked for me. This is the Java version `DataFrame customersWhoHaventOrderedTheProduct   = customers
                .join(customersWhoOrderedTheProduct.select(customersWhoOrderedTheProduct.col("email")), customers.col("email").equalTo(customersWhoOrderedTheProduct.col("email")),  "leftouter")
                .where(customersWhoOrderedTheProduct.col("email").isNull()).drop(customersWhoOrderedTheProduct.col("email"));` 

I tried the SQL equivalent but this happened `scala.MatchError: UUIDType (of class org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.types.UUIDType$)`

Comment: I am glad I could help.

Comment: I am using `Cassandra` and I have a `UUID` as a primary key. Maybe Scala is not able to match the type.

Comment: Could you try to import `com.datastax.spark.connector.types.UUIDType`?

Comment: I am running this in my IDE. I am using `setJars` to add all the dependencies to Spark. Where should I import this? I am not using any `UUID` inside the query.

Comment: I'll try to reproduce this and I'll let you know if I figure something out.

Answer (score 3):

I did it in `python`, besides I would suggest you to use integers as keys not strings.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *

samples = sc.parallelize([
    ("abonsanto@fakemail.com", "Alberto", "Bonsanto"), ("mbonsanto@fakemail.com", "Miguel", "Bonsanto"),
    ("stranger@fakemail.com", "Stranger", "Weirdo"), ("dbonsanto@fakemail.com", "Dakota", "Bonsanto")
])

keys = sc.parallelize(
    [("abonsanto@fakemail.com",), ("mbonsanto@fakemail.com",), ("dbonsanto@fakemail.com",)]
)

complex_schema = StructType([
    StructField("email", StringType(), True),
    StructField("first_name", StringType(), True),
    StructField("last_name", StringType(), True)
])

simple_schema = StructType([
    StructField("email", StringType(), True)
])

df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(samples, complex_schema)
df2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(keys, simple_schema)

df1.show()
df2.show()

df3 = df1.join(df2, df1.email == df2.email, "left_outer").where(df2.email.isNull()).show()
```

Comment: Thank you. I am using `Cassandra` so a lot of my primary keys contain a `UUID`.